# Search by text and retrieve the id

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

Is there a way to retrieve the id of a node while performing a search by text??

This is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/53cvtbv9/529/ 
As you can see, I've used 2 methods to retrieve the id of a node after the search:

```
console.log($('#jstree').jstree(true).search("Natural & Organic", false, true, '1.0'));

console.log($('#jstree').jstree('search', "Natural & Organic"));
```

In the first case I get an "undefined" output, whereas in the second case, I get a complex object (see the console).

How can I get the node id instead?? Furthermore, How can I avoid that the node found changes color?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will get that info when the `search.jstree` event is fired, check `data.res` array in console.

Demo here - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/v6guh2aw/):

```
.on('search.jstree', function(e, data) {
    console.dir(data.res);
});
```

To remove color override css rules for `.jstree-default .jstree-search` class, I made them blue in demo.

Comment: The Fiddle doesn't work... maybe you didn't update it?

Comment: it works for me.  type 'z' into the search field and check console for Array.   you should check the fiddle from my answer, not from your question